# Excel VBA RangeToHTML

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to add a button where it pastes the content of a certain range into an Outlook email. By doing so, I'm using the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Range("P25:P32,Q25:Q32,R25:R32,S25:S32,T25:T32").Select

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected"
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Range("F22").Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Range("F23").Value
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    If Toggle_3.Value = True Then
        .Display
    ElseIf Toggle_4.Value = True Then
        .Send
    End If
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Call SaveFile

End Sub
```

At line 7 of the code I used to have "P25:T32", but I changed it to that because I thought that might've been what caused the error.

When clicking the button, it gives me the error message:

> Sub or function is not defined

and it highlights the `.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)` line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?": You are copy/pasting only half code from [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) and you dont try to understand how the code works at all.

Comment: You are missing the `Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)`. See link in my first comment.

Answer (score -1):

I was missing the `Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)` as [Axel Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter) commented.